# Is dynamically generating routes from Model enum safe?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I am generating routes and responding to it dynamically by looking at the enum defined in the model. Is this safe and is there more proper method?

```
# Place
enum post_type: [:restaurant, :bar, :chill]

# routes  
scope '/places' do
    get '/:category', to: 'places#index', constraints: { category: Regexp.new( Place.post_types.keys.join("|") ) }
  end

# places_controller
def index
    if Place.respond_to? parmas[:category]
      @places = Place.send(params[:category]).order(:created_at).limit(10)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Place.send(params[:category])
> ```

Using raw user data with `send` is very dangerous, as it allows the user to call any method (`params[:category]` could be `"delete_all"` for example).
Using raw user data with `responsd_to?` can also be problematic, as this method exposes inner details of the class.

Instead, compare the user data against `Place.post_types`. It will look like this: (Untested)

```
 if  Place.post_types.has_key? params[:category]
   @places = Place.where(post_types: params[:category]).order(:created_at).limit(10)
 end
```

---

Also, dynamically creating a string for a regex is unreliable:

> ```
> Regexp.new( Place.post_types.keys.join("|") )
> ```

It will break if a key contains any special characters, for example.

Instead of using a regex, test the data against `Place.post_types`.

EDIT: Actually, it seems this contraint is unneeded as it's tested in the controller.

Comment: The query that I got to work is `Place.where(post_type: Place.post_types[params[:category]])`

Comment: @harinsa: Looks good.